# Disadvantage when adding Hyper-V Role on active server?

Tags: windows, hyper-v

is there any disadvantage / problem, if the Hyper-v role is added afterwards on an active physical Windows server (for example fileserver/dhcp server...) ?
It would be better to install it before going productive, for sure. But is there any real problem if it is done afterwards? The server needs to be rebooted afterwards, which is mandatory.

Hyper-V is a type 1 hypervisor, so I assume there is some major change underneath, wenn done.

best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would never put anything else than Hyper-V on a Hyper-V host.
Technically nothing should break but it's an extremely bad practice to use your Hyper-V host for other services.
You should aim to have the services moved to one or more virtual machines on the hyper-v once in place.
Imagine that a user gets hit by ransomware of a nasty kind, which decrypts the passwords on the physical machine, thus being able to encrypt the entire machine and not "just" a virtual fileserver. Also, don't domainjoin your hyper-V to a domain hosted by a domain controller that is a VM on the hyper-v itself. Both for the same reason as above but also to prevent you from locking yourself out completely.

Comment: Thank you very much! Especially for the security advise regarding domainjoin. Would have never thought about that.

Comment: There is actually IIRC a performance issue. Anything running on the "host" vm (because technically it is a VM) has priority - so a server process running on the server can starve the VM's. The idea here being that anything running on the server is "system level" software (updates, backup, virus scan) NOT a production setup, so it should have priority. This can be really nasty at times.

Comment: Thanks! I know that running apps/services on the Host is bad practice afterwards. The main questions was if the upgrade itself is "dangerous" afterwards.

The hypervisor should be dedicated and local services/apps should be moved to a VM afterwards. this is common best practice.

Answer (score 5):

No, there are no drawbacks (unless you have a very specific and very rare scenario like f.e. your OS / application needs an access to some proprietary hardware etc). These days all of the "generic" workload should be virtualized, there's no sense in going bare metal. Things like backup, DR and mgmt are simplified greatly.

Comment: Seconded. Technically Hyper-V role may be added on servers with other roles. But according to best practices it makes sense to virtualize “old” services (file server, etc) and let them run inside Hyper-V for better security and stability. Services running on bare metal is mostly archaistic approach nowadays. Many vendors offer now instead of “raw” servers the system with installed hypervisors or hyperconverged appliances.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers! I too think there are almost only advantages with virtualization. The disadvantages you need to cover with backup/replication & security measures.

But this encourages me to try enabling a running bare metal server as an hypervisor!
Thanks!